# How do you loop a section of code in R using information from a list, and also change the variable names based on the information in the same list?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, seurat

I have this list :

```
file_name <- list.files(path = "./GSE124395/", pattern = "\\.csv$",full.names = TRUE)
```

and I want to take each file name on that list and run the following code for each file name in order to make each item on this list into its own matrix

```
P301_3_matrix <- read.delim(file = './GSE124395//GSM3531672_P301_3_CRYOMIXED11.coutt.csv')

P301_3_matrix <- data.frame(P301_3_matrix[,-1], row.names=P301_3_matrix[,1])
P301_3_matrix <- as.matrix(P301_3_matrix)

P301_3_colname <- read.table(file = './GSE124395//GSE124395_celseq_barcodes.192.txt', header = FALSE, row.names = 1)
P301_3_colname <- data.frame(P301_3_colname[,-1], col=P301_3_colname[,1])
P301_3_colname <- as.matrix(P301_3_colname)
dim(P301_3_colname)
colnames(P301_3_matrix) <- P301_3_colname[,1]
```

Here is the output of this code: [image]

And I want to repeat this code for each './GSE.csv' file, and change the P301_3_matrix name using information from the ./GSE file name.

Here is my attempt so far, but it returns the error: Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument

```
matrix_list <- list()               # Create empty list
matrix_list

for (i in 1:length(file_name)) {
  for (i in file_name){
    matrix <- read.delim(file = file_name[i])
  
  matrix <- data.frame(matrix[,-1], row.names=matrix[,1])
  matrix <- as.matrix(matrix) #<- makes the excel file into a matrix
  
  matrix_colname <- read.table(file = './GSE124395//GSE124395_celseq_barcodes.192.txt', header = FALSE, row.names = 1)
  matrix_colname <- data.frame(matrix_colname[,-1], col=matrix_colname[,1])
  matrix_colname <- as.matrix(matrix_colname)
  dim(matrix_colname)
  colnames(matrix) <- matrix_colname[,1]
  
  matrix_list[[i]] <- matrix
  
  }
 
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense and thanks for reading!

**UPDATE: I put an answer in the comments below**

Comment: Can you provide a simplified example? i.e. a subset of p301_3_matrix

Comment: I have tried to answer. Note that your question would benefit from a minimal reproducible example. You are not using the `seurat` package, just reading some files in a loop.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean :> @Ali @Colombo I basically used ```getGEOSuppFiles("GSE124395") ``` to get the dataset, and then unzipped the files using ```untar()```. The code I had with the matrix was an attempt (you can probably tell I am very very new at coding heh) to turn the resulting .csv files into a matrix format. I'm sorry that I'm not being too helpful here :> I really do appreciate you two's help and advice!

Answer (score 0):

```
read_expression_csv = function(file){
    table = read.delim(file)
    table = data.frame(table[,-1], row.names = table[,1])
    as.matrix(table)
    }


read_barcodes = function(file){
    barcodes = read.table(file, header=FALSE, row.names=1)
    barcodes = data.frame(barcodes[,-1], col=barcodes[,1])
    as.matrix(barcodes)
    }


get_expression_matrix(file, barcodes){
    expr = read_expression_csv(file)
    colnames(expr) = barcodes
    expr
    }


barcodes = read_barcodes("./GSE124395//GSE124395_celseq_barcodes.192.txt")[,1]

files <- list.files(path = "./GSE124395/", pattern = "\\.csv$",full.names = TRUE)
expressions = lapply(files, get_expression_matrix, barcodes=barcodes)
names(expressions) = files
```

No need to prealocate list of results thanks to `lapply`.

I just put your code into a few functions to isolate and name its logic. Can't guarantee that it will be working without the CSV files. I am almost sure you are doing something strange with `read.delim`, simple `read.table` with proper parametrization should be working well. After all, `read.delim` is just a wrapper around `read.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I think this is the answer to my question in part. This results in a list of a matrix for each file name.

```
mylist<-list.files(path = "./GSE124395/", pattern = "\\.csv$",full.names = TRUE)

LoopList <- list()

for (i in 1:length(mylist)){
  
  matrix_input <- read.delim(file =mylist[i])
  matrix_input <- data.frame(matrix_input[,-1], row.names=matrix_input[,1]) 
  matrix_input <- as.matrix(matrix_input) 
  
  colname_input <- read.delim(file =mylist[i])
  colname_input <- read.table(file = './GSE124395//GSE124395_celseq_barcodes.192.txt', header = FALSE, row.names = 1) 
  colname_input <- data.frame(colname_input[,-1], col=colname_input[,1]) 
  colname_input <- as.matrix(colname_input) 
  colnames(matrix_input) <- colname_input[,1] 
  
  LoopList[[i]]<-matrix_input
}

LoopList[1:5]
```

Hopefully this helps someone else!